# Python - input of file path

Tags: python, file, path, python-2.x

this code works fine when I put the path of the file myself. but when I want to get it from users `raw_input()` it doesn't work. what can I do?

```
import string
import random

print "enter number between 6 and 20"
n = raw_input()
print "enter pathway of file"
p = raw_input() 

print "creating a new text file"
new_file = open(p, "w")  #the error on this line
m = int(n)


print random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)

for i in range(0,m):
    for j in range(0,m):
        new_file.write(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase))
    new_file.write("\n")
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" how? Also, what path are you typing in at the prompt?

Comment: Can you please describe exactly what error is given by Python?

Comment: can you provide a sample of input and output error that you get?

Comment: sample of input - "c:\Users\USER\Desktop\bar.txt"
output - IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\USER\\"c:\\Users
\\USER\\Desktop\\bar.txt"'

Comment: Your code works on my machine. How are you running your code? If you're in an interactive session, previously defined functions may be affecting your current code. (for instance, if you did `def open` at any point).

Comment: i run it from cmd and there is not "def" - this is all the code.. thank you for your helping anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message you quoted, it looks like you're adding doublequotes to your user input and escaping the backslashes. Don't do that.

Instead of entering

```
"c:\\Users \\USER\\Desktop\\bar.txt"
```

at the prompt, enter:

```
C:\users\USER\Desktop\bar.txt
```

Comment: @bar if this solved your question, you should consider marking it as ["accepted"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.