# Why does a user inputted path return file not found?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have code designed to take a file from a path I input at runtime. When I enter the path I expect to see the contents of the file but instead I'm met with the error `No such file or directory`. After doing some googling I found a SO post here [Python - input of file path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30308309/3124292) but the accepted answer didn't apply. **Why am I not getting my expected results?**
**note**: I am using visual studios 2017 to  run this.

My current source is:

```
def GetFile(input):
    end_ = ""
    data = open(input, 'r')
    for line in data:
        end_ = end_ + line
    data.close()
    return end_
dir = raw_input("Please enter the directory in which the file exists: ")

out = GetFile(dir)

print(out) #To see what was taken from the file
```

I have also tried using another function based off of suggestions in python docs as follows:

```
   def GetFile2(input):
        end2 = ""
        with open(input,'r') as f:
            end2 = f.read()
        return end2
```

When I try either one, my result looks like:
[image: Imgur]

I have also tried the following to no avail:

- Moving file to a new path
- Changing directory names to lower case
- changing `\` to `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Windows (or rather Explorer) is configured not to show file extensions. The actual name of your file is `C:\Users\Semaphore\Desktop\test.txt.txt`.